# iOS push notification in PHP, can't find a working solution

Tags: php, ios, notifications, push

The push notifications on a project stopped working and I can't find the reason. It doesn't give me any error code. The fastest solution would be to find a piece of code that I can modify and try, debug and use. I read that Apple changed the protocol recently so I'd like to use a recent code, but I can't find anything usable. Did anyone work on that recenty and would be willing to share the code at least to find the problem?

I'd like to share the code of that project but it's quite complex, using a lot of classes, etc.

I tried using pushtry.com to make sure that the certificate is still valid and I'm using the correct token etc and it worked.

Unfortunately, I don't quite understand protocols etc, I've read that the new solution needs to use HTTP2; the server admin told me that curl doesn't support SSL (which is used by some of the codes I tried using). And they say it's better to use openssl s_client. But I don't really know what that means.

Thanks anyone who can help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with packing the items, however I have no idea why it worked before and stopped working. And why the original code was much more complex.

The original code:

```
function _packFrame(array $packed_items): string {
    $items = implode('', $packed_items);
    return pack('CN', 2, \strlen($items)) . $items;
}

function _packItem($id, $data): string {
    return \pack('Cn', $id, \strlen($data)) . $data;
}

$items = _packItem(1, \pack('H*', $device_token))
            . _packItem(3, \pack('H*', $notification_identifier))
            . _packItem(2, $payload_json);
$data_to_write = _packFrame($items);
```

New code:

```
$data_to_write = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $device_token) . pack('n', strlen($payload_json)) . $payload_json;
```